# Update value once write completes in Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm trying to update one value after a write completes (in a Cloud Function) but it just wont work (I'm sure this is a stupidly simple problem). Code below:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const firebase = require('firebase');

 admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
 exports.createMessage = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
        const json = JSON.parse(request.query.json); // == "{'start':0, 'end':0}"
        json.start = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
        admin.database().ref('/messages/').push(json).then(snapshot => {

            //Here is the problem. Whatever I try here it won't work to retrieve the value.
            //So, how to I get the "start" value, which has been written to the DB (TIMESTAMP value)?
            var startValue = snapshot.ref.child('start').val();

            snapshot.ref.update({ end: (startValue + 85800000) }).then(snapshot2=>{
                response.redirect(303, snapshot.ref);
            });
        });
 });
```

Is the problem that I'm using admin.database()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a bug in Firebase or if I'm using it wrong, but if I try to call any method on the `snapshot`-reference I will only get an error saying: `TypeError: snapshot.xxx is not a function` where xxx is the function name i try to use (for example: child(...), forEach(...), etc).

However, the following seems to fix the issue with the `snapshot`:

```
admin.database().ref('/messages/').push(json).once('value').then(snapshot => {
```

instead of:

```
admin.database().ref('/messages/').push(json).then(snapshot => {
```

My *un*educated guess is that the `then`-promise, for the `push`-function returns some faulty `snapshot` since the only thing that seems to work is `snapshot.key`.

Also, if I'm not mistaken, doesn't my solution make two reads now, instead of one? Since `push` will write and then (supposedly) read and return the written value and then I read it once more with `once(value)`.

Does anyone has any further insights into this problem?

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
var startValue = snapshot.ref.child('start').val();
```

doesn't actually retrieve any values.  Take a look at the docs for [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot).  Reach into that snapshot directly with [child()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot#child) - you don't need the `ref`.  Maybe this is what you meant?

```
var startValue = snapshot.child('start').val();
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work. In fact, I can't use any method at all on the snapshot referece. Error log: 'TypeError: snapshot.child is not a function'. I "solved" my issue, see my answer for further details.